# How can you cancel loading here maps with js?

Tags: javascript, angular, here-api, heremaps

I am using here maps for javascript 3.1. Is there a way to cancel or interrupt loading here maps? In real time scenario this will happen on clicking back button. When routing back to previous page, here maps are still loading in the background.

I tried with dispose() method but it's not supported.

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
});

// Load map asynchronously
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var map = new H.Map(
  document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
  maptypes.vector.normal.map,
  {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
  }
);

// Cancel map loading
platform.dispose();
```